# Interval and percentage algorithm

Tags: algorithms, percentages, interval-arithmetic

I have a problem that I can not solve.
I want to create the following algorithm:
For an interval [a, b].
If a variable x (between a and b) is close to the center of the interval we will output 100% and if we move away from the center the value decreases to 95% when we arrive in both sides of the interval.

Comment: You need to define your problem first. What does it mean "close to the center"? You want a function that return 100 is x is a midpoint of the interval and 95 if it's not or something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f(x)=\begin {cases} 1-0.05\frac{\frac{a+b}2-x}{\frac {b-a}2}& x\le \frac {a+b}2\\
1-0.05\frac{x-\frac{a+b}2}{\frac {b-a}2}& x\gt \frac {a+b}2 \end{cases}$$